# Proguard keep interface method variable names

Tags: android, proguard

I'm trying to prevent proguard from obfuscating interface method variable names. My proguard.pro has the following configurations but still the method variables appear as a, b etc.

> -keep public class * {
>       public *; }
>
> -keepclassmembers class * {
>       public *; }
>
> -keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature
>   -keepparameternames
>   -keep public interface com.test.listener.MyListener { *; }

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to your problem ? I am facing the same issue. Thx

Answer (score 1):

`-keep interface com.yourpackage.**{*;}` is what you need. It will keep all your interface's name and methods.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck. Same behaviour on Android Studio and Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

```
    -keep public interface com.yourpackqge.yourapp.**{*;}
```

This works for me