# Proguard keep parameter names for interface and abstract class

Tags: android, proguard

I am trying to prevent proguard from obfuscating interface (or abstract class) methods parameters.

Lets say I have this interface in my lib :

```
package com.mypackage;
public interface MyLibListener {
    void onSomething(boolean success, String message); 
}
```

And this proguard file :

```
-keepparameternames
-keep interface com.mypackage.MyLibListener {
    *;
}
```

Then I assemble release and I get :

```
package com.mypackage;
public interface MyLibListener {
    void onSomething(boolean var1, String var2);
}
```

Same thing with abstract classes or using `@Keep` annotations. Obfuscation option `keepparameternames` seems to work only for regular classes. Any idea? Thanks!

(related SO : [How to not obfuscate interface methods & it's parameters using Progaurd in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290615/how-to-not-obfuscate-interface-methods-its-parameters-using-progaurd-in-andro) and [Proguard keep interface method variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28162823/proguard-keep-interface-method-variable-names))

Comment: was this ever resolved? I have the same issue

Comment: @sinek I tried so many things (at the time I asked) but never found the solution :( I did not try recently sorry. Tell us if you find the way

Comment: I've resolved my issue with the compiler "-parameters" flag

Answer (score 9):

Add following ProGuard [options](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/attributes) to your configuration.

> -keepattributes MethodParameters

If your class file hava method parameters metadata (compiled using Java8 `-parameters` or etc...)`, ProGuard will keep the metadata.

Answer (score 2):

To keep all interface methods:

```
-keep interface * {
   <methods>;
}
```

To keep all public and protected methods, which could be used by reflection:

```
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    public protected <methods>;
}
```

While I don't understand, why one would want to keep `abstract` classes, which cannot be instanced anyway, therefore it's pointless to keep & know their names. In theory, one could exclude all that is **not** `abstract` with rules which start with `-keep !abstract`, but that's kind of redundant.

Answer (score -3):

Your proguard file may lack some `-keepattributes`, especially a `-keepattributes Signature`.

Check [this example proguard configuration for a library](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/examples#library) from the proguard documentation to look for ideas.